# Error Received when using liveserver for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions

I was wondering if anyone possibly know the solution for this error

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
```

I'm trying to run a live server while working on my html file but it's not letting me . I restarted my pc..same issue... restarted program...same issue... used localhost... same issue ...switched setting to chrome browser....same issue..

I also added (code below) to my JSON Settings file...Still running to the same issues. It was running fine last night and this morning it completely stopped working.

```
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"
```

Comment: Which port are You using for LiveServer?

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
I changed my settings in settings.json(live server extension settings)
to this .
It started working again !!!
I hope it's useful

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
"liveServer.settings.port": 5500,
"liveServer.settings.https": {
    "enable": false,
    "key": "",
    "passphrase": "",
    "cert": " "
},
"liveServer.settings.proxy": {
    "enable": true,
    "baseUri": "http://127.0.0.1:80",
    "proxyUri": "http://127.0.0.1:80"
},
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
"liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
"liveServer.settings.host": "127.0.0.1:80",
"liveServer.settings.useLocalIp": true
```

}

Answer (score 1):

ok so i had this same problem today and what i did was to go into file>setting look up live server and edit json and delete the settings there and saved and reloaded and it seem to start to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Open `VSCode` and click **File**, **Preferences**, **Settings** than type in search settings `Liveserver port` The LiveServer Settings Port option will appear, click `Edit in settings.json.`
And set **`"liveServer.settings.port": 5500,`** save and close `settings.json`.

---

And If you have a `.vscode` directory in your `project directory` then remove it.[image]

---

Restart VSCode and run Liveserver and keep on Coding! :-) Now it's should up and running;-)

Answer (score -1):

Helpful screenshot:

[image]

I typed exactly same URLs in these two boxes and Viola! The issue was resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30575529)